# onUserAfterLogin popup - Joomla 3.6.4 Plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, custom-component, plugin-events

I need to create a plugin that displays a popup when an user makes a log in on my Joomla 3.6.4 website. I know that I need to create a Plugin and trigger the onUserAfterLogin event, but I don't know how to create HTML and Javascript from inside a Plugin. So, my **popuplogin.xml** is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.6" type="plugin" group="user" method="upgrade">
        <name>Popuplogin</name>
        <author>XX</author>
        <creationDate>08/03/2018</creationDate>
        <copyright>2018</copyright>
        <license>GNU General Public License</license>
        <authorEmail>XXX</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>XXX</authorUrl>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <description>Plugin to display a modal after UserLogin</description>
        <files>
                <filename plugin="popuplogin">popuplogin.php</filename>
                <filename>index.html</filename>
        </files>
</extension>
```

And my **popuplogin.php** is:

```
    <?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;


class PlgUserPopuplogin extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAfterLogin($options)
        {
              return 'I think I need to place Javascript/HTML here';
 }
}

?>
```

With these files, nothing happens, even if I place a simple `<p>I am the login popup</p>` inside return. Can you please explain to me how can I properly display a message using a Plugin in Joomla?

Comment: Silly question, but have you enabled the plugin?

Comment: silly question, but why are you still on J 3.6 when updating to current 3.8 is so easy and painless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `onUserAfterLogin()` should be a boolean -- ie `true` or `false`. The idea is that you can use this event handler to do additional validation on the login, so if you return `false`, it indicates that the login should be rejected.

What you want to do is quite different; you're trying to add content to the page after login. There's several ways of doing this.

- Option 1: If you're not worried about a modal, you could just use Joomla's message system to tell the user something:

  ```
  JError::raiseNotice(100, "Put whatever message you want to tell the user here.");
  ```
- Option 2: Use an extension like [Regular Labs Modals](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/modals/), so that you can pop up a modal alert with minimum code. You'd probably not need much more than a single line in your existing plugin to call the modal with the message you want to show.
- Option 3: Write the modal yourself using JavaScript, and inject it into the page using `addScript()` or `addScriptDeclaration()`, as described in the Joomla documentation here: https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript